# Possible ways to compress Apache Arrow RecordBatch?

Tags: c++, apache-arrow

I am working on C++ and trying to reduce network traffic of Flight RPC by compressing the `RecordBatch` object.

What's the best way to make a `RecordBatch` compact? I found that `RecordBatch` consists of `Array`. Is it good to directly compress `ArrayData`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the caveat that in my own testing, I've never found compression to help substantially, Arrow already supports compression and this can be enabled (with some finagling) by setting IPC options.

For example, if you have a DoGet, pass an [IpcWriteOptions](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/ipc.html#_CPPv4N5arrow3ipc15IpcWriteOptionsE) with [compression](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/ipc.html#_CPPv4N5arrow3ipc15IpcWriteOptions5codecE) enabled to [RecordBatchStream](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/flight.html#_CPPv4N5arrow6flight17RecordBatchStreamE). Then Arrow/Flight will compress body buffers for you and the other end (assuming it supports compression) will transparently decompress them.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Do you mind shedding light on the compression benchmark after setting IPC options? It's awesome that data is transparently decompressed by DoGet, but it will be helpful If I can measure size after compression.

Comment: You can read through the discussion here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10351